# Flow does not allow organization wide mail address if automated mail address

Tags: visual-workflow, apex-email-service, process-automation, organization-wide

I created a flow which send email to the customer. The flow used the organization-wide email address. The email address is user a specific email.
But if the customer answers the email it will be sent to the organization-wide email address.

If I try to change the email address to a automated email address (email services) the flow display an error.
**Because the Automated Process User’s email address isn’t valid, this flow can’t send emails for actions or errors. On the Process Automation Settings page in Setup, the Automated Process User Email Address must specify an organization-wide email address for the system administrator profile.**

f the customer answers the mail, I would like it to be sent directly to salesforce. Possible?